# Building project failed after integrating GCM

Tags: java, android, google-cloud-messaging

I am simply trying to add GCM on my app and I followed the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/android/client) . After adding **classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:1.3.0-beta1'** this line to top level class path , I can not build the project and it shows build failed error in terminal

**Top level build.gradle**

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.0.0'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:1.3.0-beta1'
    }
}
```

**App build.gradle**

```
    dependencies {
        compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: '*.jar')
        compile project(':SocialArticleFramework')
        compile project(':android-support-v7-appcompat')
        compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.0'
        compile "org.igniterealtime.smack:smack-android:4.1.0"
        compile "org.igniterealtime.smack:smack-android-extensions:4.1.0"
        compile "org.igniterealtime.smack:smack-sasl-provided:4.1.0"
        compile "org.igniterealtime.smack:smack-tcp:4.1.0"
        compile "org.igniterealtime.smack:smack-im:4.1.0"
        compile 'com.diegocarloslima:fgelv:0.1.+@aar'
        compile 'de.greenrobot:eventbus:2.4.0'
        compile 'in.srain.cube:ultra-ptr:1.0.9'
        compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.3'
        compile 'org.apmem.tools:layouts:1.9@aar'
        compile 'com.github.navasmdc:MaterialDesign:1.5@aar'
        compile 'se.emilsjolander:StickyScrollViewItems:1.1.0'
    }

   android {
    compileSdkVersion 21
    buildToolsVersion "21.1.2"

    sourceSets {
        main {
            manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
            java.srcDirs = ['src']
            resources.srcDirs = ['src']
            aidl.srcDirs = ['src']
            renderscript.srcDirs = ['src']
            res.srcDirs = ['res']
            assets.srcDirs = ['assets']
        }

        // Move the tests to tests/java, tests/res, etc...
        instrumentTest.setRoot('tests')

        // Move the build types to build-types/<type>
        // For instance, build-types/debug/java, build-types/debug/AndroidManifest.xml, ...
        // This moves them out of them default location under src/<type>/... which would
        // conflict with src/ being used by the main source set.
        // Adding new build types or product flavors should be accompanied
        // by a similar customization.
        debug.setRoot('build-types/debug')
        release.setRoot('build-types/release')
    }

    defaultConfig {
        multiDexEnabled = true
    }

    dexOptions {
        preDexLibraries = false
        incremental true
        javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
    }
 }
```

> Execution failed for task ':myModule:processDebugResources'.
>   com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException:

For more output in terminal , pls see [here](https://gist.githubusercontent.com/sannysinghs/f45ab3fc9c37caef0052/raw/af33d3a35c00c321493344d9e5a4465da5d6373f/GCM%20Error).
Any help! , thanks.

Comment: Is there anything else after internal.ExecException: ? It woul be useful if there is more information

Comment: Hi @JorgeCasariego , I've added gist file to describe more output in terminal.

Comment: Do you have multiDexEnabled true in your android -> buildTypes inside your build.gradle?

Comment: yes @JorgeCasariego , i had already enabled

Comment: any one found solution? i am facing same problem

Comment: Hey @RipalTamboli , try remove some of dependencies esp MaterialDesign for me . After remove this dependency i can now build and run project .

Comment: @Sanny: i haven't yet included MaterialDesign dependencies

Answer (score 1):

`File-> Project structure -> "module" -> Dependencies -> + -> Library dependency`  and select GCM from there.

Comment: Having what seems to be the same problem, but not seeing the GCM library listed in the Choose Library Dependency...

Comment: play-services library contains GCM in it.